# Which Pokemon are animal based?

Tags: pokemon

I have been thinking about this question for a while now. Since many Pokemon  are based around animals, which animals are Pokemon based on? I ask for the family of the animals, such as dogs, cats, mice and so on. The complete definition is in [this link](http://a-z-animals.com/reference/animal-classification/).

**I would like a complete list if possible.**

Comment: should be a lot, there's only 700 pokemon so far, and god knows how many animal on earth. That said, check this out, [15 Animals that haven't been made into Pokémon](http://www.gamezone.com/originals/15-animals-that-haven-t-been-made-into-pokemon)

Comment: note for future readers, my comment above was made before the edit, and the original question asked about what animal that doesn't have a Pokemon version of it, hence, my comment. But since the OP decide to change the question, my comment becomes obsolete, however, I decide to keep it because it has an interesting article about some animals that haven't been made into Pokémon.

Comment: @Dragon since there's 721 pokemon until XY, and also most of them are based on animal, I think I can write down all the list, but it's need more time to write them all XD

Comment: Is it okay if I'm not write all of the full evolution of one Pokemon? Just like my edited on Sam's answer?

Comment: @JTR As long as it is relevant, I guess it's not a problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a list of all the animals I know of sorry if I typed it wrong.

- parrot = Chatot
- elephant = Panphy's Family
- shark = Sharpedo
- piranha = Carvanha
- raccoon = Zigzagoon's Family
- giraffe = Girafarig
- bee = beedrill, combee's family
- caterpillar = Caterpie, wrumple
- mouse = Pichu's family
- rat = Ratatta, Raticate
- house cat = Meowth, Glameow's family
- hyena = Poochyena's family
- spiders (different species) = Spinarak's Family, Joltink's family
- rattle snake = Ekans
- Cobra = Arbok
- Crocodile = Totodile's family
- alligator = Sandile's family
- camel = numel's family
- ostrich = Doduo's family (technically dodo I think)
- pidgeon = pidove's family
- duck = Psiduck's family, duclett
- pelican = Pelliper
- angler fish = Chinchou's family
- whale = Wailmer's family
- coelacanth = Relicanth
- horseshoe crab = Kabuto's family
- crab = Kraby's family
- lobster = corphish's family
- goldfish = goldeen's family
- carp = magikarp
- clam = shelder's family
- morray eel = Tynamo's family (?)
- squid = inkay's family
- jellyfish = tentacool's family, frillish's family
- octopus = octillery
- fox = eevee's family, Vulpix's family
- dog = growlithe, electrike
- butterfly = butterfree, beautyfly
- owl = hoothoot's family
- walrus = spheal's family
- zebra = blitzle's family
- pony = ponyta
- cow = miltank
- buffalo = tauros, bouffalant
- polar bear = cubchoo's family
- brown bear = teddiursa's family
- ant eater = Heatmor
- ant = durrant
- praying mantis = Scyther's family
- Kangaroo = kangaskhan
- monkeys = mankey
- apes = primeape, slaking
- humans = tyrogue's family, throh, sawk, machop's line
- ladybug = ledyba's family
- eagle = staraptor
- falcon = talonflame, Pidgeotto, Pidgeot
- bat = zubat's family, woobat's family, noibat's family,
- hermit crab = dwebble's family
- mudskipper = mudkip's family, wooper line
- gecko = treecko's family
- turtle = squirtle's family
- tortoise = turtwig's family
- hedgehog = shaymin, cyndaquil
- slug = slugma, shellos's family
- snail = magcargo
- penguin = piplup's family
- frog = froakie's family, poliwag's family
- barnacle = binacle's family
- beaver = bidoof's family
- moth = venomoth, dustox, volcarona
- Rhinoceros = rhyhorn' family
- hippopatamus = hippopotas's family
- Mammoth = Mammoswine
- Sloth= slakoth line,
- Lion= Shinx's line
- Crow: Murkrow's line
- Pig: tepig's line
- swine= Swinub's line
- hercules beetle= heracross
- toad= Bulbasaur's line
- Tapir= Drowzee's line, Munna's line

there is more but that all I can think of right now.

Comment: Can you also mention which Pokemon is based on this animal? As it is, it's just a big list of animals so it's hard to relate it back to Pokemon.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but is this the full list of animals that covers all the pokemon or just most of them? is it possible to get the full list? tell me if it's too much work to make a full list, then i'll give this as the right answer

Comment: this is not the full list, these were just a bunch I could think of

Comment: i'll keep adding more from time to time though

Answer (score 8):

I tried my best to write down all of the Pokemons out there, here's the list :

- Bird : Pidgey's Family, Spearow's Family, Farfetch'd, Articuno, Zapdos, Moltres, Hoothoot's Family, Togetic & Togekiss, Natu's Family, 
  Murkrow's Family, Skarmory, Lugia, Ho-oh, Taillow's Family, Wingull's Family, Swablu's family, Starly's Family, Chatot, Cresselia, Pidove's family, Sigilyph, Ducklett's family, Rufflet's family, Vullaby's family, Fletchling's family, Hawlucha, Yveltal
- Flightless Bird : Doduo's family, Delibird, Torchic's family, Piplup's family
- Ancient Bird : Aerodactyl, Archen's family
- Canidae : Vulpix's family, Growlithe's family, Eevee's family, Abra's family, Snubbull's family, Houndour's family, Smeargle, Raikou, Entei, Suicune, Poochyena's family, Electrike's family,
  Absol, Riolu's family, Lillipup's family, Zorua's family, Fennekin's family, Furfrou, Swirlix's family
- Felidae : Meowth's family, Mewtwo, Mew, Hoppip, Skitty's family, Shinx's family, Glameow's family, Purrloin's family, Litleo's family, Espurr's family, Volcanion
- Turtle : Squirtle's family, Torkoal, Turtwig's family, Tirtouga's family
- Frog : Bulbasaur's family, Poliwag's family, Croagunk's family, Tympole's family, Froakie's family
- Lizard : Charmander & Charmeleon, Treecko's family,  Scraggy's family, Helioptile's family, Lickitung, Kecleon
- Caterpillar : Caterpie, Weedle, Wurmple, Burmy, Sewaddle, Venipede, Larvesta, Scatterbug
- Pupa : Metapod, Kakuka, Pupitar, Silcoon, Cascoon, Swadloon, Spewpa
- Butterfly : Butterfree, Beautifly, Vivilion
- Bee : Beedrill, Combee, Vaspiquin
- Moth : Venomoth, Dustox, Masquerain, Mothim, Volcarona
- Rodent : Ratatta's family, Pichu's family, Plusle, Minun, Bidoof's family, Pachirisu, Emolga, Victini, Dedenne
- Snake : Ekans's family, Onix's family, Seviper, Milotic, Serperior
- Shrew : Sandhrew's family, Drilbur's family
- Rabbit : Nidoran (male)'s family, Nidoran (female)'s family, Wigglytuff, Azurill's family, Buneary's family, Bunnelby's family
- Bat : zubat's family, woobat's family, noibat's family
- Cicada : Paras's family, Nincada's family
- Duck : Psyduck's family, Duclett's family
- Sloth : Slakoth & Vigoroth, Slowpoke's family
- Ape : Mankey's family, Aipom's family, Slaking, Chimchar's family, Pansage's family, Pansear's family, Panpour's family, Darmanitan, Electabuzz & Electrivire
- [Bovidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bovidae) : Abra's family, Tauros, Mareep's family, Stantler, Miltank, Shaymin (Sky form), Arceus, Deerling's family, Bouffalant, Cobalion, Terrakion, Virizion, Skiddo's family, Xerneas
- Jellyfish : Tentacool's family, Frillish's family
- [Equidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidae) : Ponyta's family, Blitzle's family, Keldeo
- [Pinniped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinniped) : Seel's family, Spheal's family
- Clams : Shellder's family, Clamperl
- Tapir : Drowzee's family, Munna's family
- Crab : Krabby's family
- Lobster : Corphish's family, Clauncher's family
- Rhynoceros : Rhyhorn's family
- Kangaroo : Kangaskhan
- Seahorse : Horsea's family, Sklerp's family
- Goldfish : Goldeen's family
- Starfish : Staryu's family
- Mantis : Scyther's family, Kabutops, Leavanny
- Beetle : Pinsir, Heracross, Karrablast's family
- Carp : Magikarp
- Bass : Feebas, Basculin
- Mollusca : Omanyte's family, Shuckle, Slugma's family, Shellos's family, Shelmet's family, Binacle's family, Goomy & Sliggoo, Zygarde
- Seahorse Crab : Kabuto
- Bear : Munchlax's family, Teddiursa's family, Cubchoo's family, Pancham's family
- Hedgehog : Cyndaquil's family, Shaymin (Land form), Chespin's family
- Crocodile : Totodile's family, Sandile's family
- Ferret : Sentret's family, Patrat's family
- Ladybug : Ledian's family
- Spider : Spinarak's family, Joltik's family
- Angler Fish : Chinchou's family
- Salamander : Wooper's family, Mudkip's Family
- Pig : Swinub, Spoink's family, Tepig's family
- Remora : Remoraid
- Octopus : Octillery
- Manta Ray : Mantyke's family
- Elephant : Phanpy's family
- Racoon : Zigzagoon's family
- Firefly : Volbeat, Illumise
- Piranha : Carvanha
- Shark : Sharpedo
- Whale : Wailmer's family, Kyogre
- Camel : Numel's family
- Ant : Trapinch, Durrant, Genesect
- Mongoose : Zangoose
- Catfish : Barboach's family
- Eel : Hauntail, Gorebyss, Tynamo's family
- Coelacanth : Relicanth
- [Discus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discus_(fish)) : Luvdisc
- Cricket : Kriketot
- Weasel : Sneasel's family, Buizel's family, Mienfoo's family
- Skunk : Stunky's family
- Hippopotamus : Hippopotas's family
- Scorpion : Gligar's family, Skorupi's family
- [Freshwater Butterflyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshwater_butterflyfish) : Finneon's family
- Dragonfly : Yanma's family
- Otter : Oshawott's family
- Centipede : Venipede's family
- Hermit Crab : Dwebble's family
- Chincilla : Mincinno's family
- [Sunfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_sunfish) : Alomomola
- Flatfish : Stunfisk
- Anteater : Heatmor
- Mite : Magnemite, Bergmite
- Dinosaur (if it's count as an animal) : Cubone's family, Lapras, Chikorita's family, Larvitar & Tyranitar, Breloom, Lairon & Aggron, Anorith's family, Tropius,
  Bagon, Groudon, Cranidos's family, Shieldon's family, Gible's family, Dialga, Deino's family, Tyrunt's family, Amaura's family, Avalugg
- Dragon (if it's count as an animal) : Charizard, Gyarados, Dratini's family, Flygon, Bagon's family, Rayquaza, Palkia, Giratina, Axew's family, Druddigon, Deino's family, Reshiram, Zekrom, Kyurem, Goodra

That's my full list, I hope I'm not missed one of them.

Almost all Pokemon based on animal, that we're familiar with, or even animal that we doesn't know before.

Many of them are combined from two species at once, like Eevee's evolution that have some characteristic of Canidae and Felidae, so I put it on one of the family.

Source Various articles on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net)

Comment: I'll update as soon as possible.

Comment: mudkip is a mudskipper while whooper is based on a axolotl

Comment: @SamHendriks yeah I know, just like I said, Mudkip and Whooper are based on more than one animal. Mudkip based on mudskipper but also have some trait with salamander and axolotl because it's gills, and Whooper also true based on axolotl but also salamander moreover, Quagsire, Whooper's evolution is based on giant salamander